# How can I solve $4x^2y''-12xy'+(4x^2+15)y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this equation $4x^2y''-12xy'+(4x^2+15)y=0$ and I used this $y'=yz(x)$ ,then I got equation $z^2+z-\dfrac{3z}{x}+1+\dfrac{15}{4x}=0$ Can anyone help me? I am desperate.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you do it in that way. But one common method could be like this:

The original ODE could be written as :

$y^{'} -\frac{4x^2+15}{12x}y=\frac{x}{3}$

Then you denote $p(x)=-\frac{4x^2+15}{12x}$, $q(x)=\frac{x}{3}$, then you can have

$y = e^{-\int p(x)dx}\{\int q(x)e^{\int p(x)dx}dx+C\}$

You can continue on this and get your result.